# How do we attract playtesters for our online superhero game platform?

Tags: tools, online-roleplaying, play-by-post, playtesting

My friend and I are building a CMS specifically designed for online roleplaying. For the playtest we are using it to run a superheroes-themed game. We've built in-site tools to help making posting and character creation easier, and we're continually working on it based on playtester feedback.

Right now we have a few playtesters helping us to test the system, but they're all people we know — we have no experience with folks who are unfamiliar with our system and how we are doing things.

How do we attract folks to be playtesters for our game/platform ?

Comment: Related: [Where can I find online playtesting groups?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78506/where-can-i-find-online-playtesting-groups)

Comment: FYI, we have [Community Ads available for free](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/community-promotion-ads-2016) for various positive RPG-related causes like this one. (Provided the community approves.)

Comment: Things I did not know for $500 Alex (Tribek). Thank you for the tip doppelgreener, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you want players for a specific game you're going to run on your platform, or just people who will run their own games on your platform and let you know how it went, but most of these options should work for both.

A friend and I have tried most of these for our tabletop game & game support software projects, and the results were pretty good.

- Take out ads in rpg industry publications. [You can do that here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6717/community-promotion-ads-2017), as doppelgreener mentioned, or in indie rpg publications like [Worlds Without Master](http://www.worldswithoutmaster.com/home) relatively cheaply
- Ask for interested playtesters on a forum like BoardGameGeek.com or the forums at Roll20.net
- Trade playtesting/reviewing of other people's work for them testing yours on a site like [Villages.cc](https://villages.cc/?logo). Or, directly pay beta users to try it out through something like UpWork.com
- Visit a local gaming con or meetup, and bring fliers with links to your site. Offer to demo it live, if possible

Good luck!