# Finding Play Testers

Tags: gm-techniques, homebrew, new-players, playtesting

Any advice on communities or forums where I can find play testers for a new tabletop role play game?

It's designed for casual players to game together virtually. So imagine pen & pen style RPG played over WhatsApp or Slack. Games usually take about an hour or two and there's a whole element designed for off the cuff role play between games.

A large part of the game is story creation mechanics that make games really quick to setup. This is the bit we're working on the most at the moment.

Rather than hand this over to someone else to run, like in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78506/where-can-i-find-online-playtesting-groups), I'd like to have an involved discovery session with the players. Ideally looking to understand how the feel about the game as much as watch them play.

Any suggestions on where to look would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've removed the link to your patreon since using questions and answers here to post a game advertisement isn't what we want to see. You may however post [a free community promotion ad](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7721/community-promotion-ads-2018) which will show in our sidebar as long as the community approves of it. Please note the image requirements for your ad mentioned in that post.

Comment: Thanks for the linked question. It only suggests roll20 which is a great site but I was hoping for other communities.  Maybe we could reopen the other question?

Comment: Gotcha, apologies, didn't mean to post like an ad...

Comment: I've placed a maximum-size bounty on the other question to draw attention to it. Hopefully it might get more & varied responses over the coming week. Thanks for understanding removing the link, please do feel welcome to use our community ads — they exist to promote projects like yours.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very kind! (Getting used to using this stackexchange)